# EasyMock expected void

Tags: jpa-2.0, easymock

Just trying the EasyMock for the first time.

I seem to get it going but I am immediately halted with the fact that the mocked class runs a method "returning" void (EntityManager.remove(abc)).

I am able to mock the EntityManger partly to begin testing, i.e.

```
EasyMock.expect(this.mockManager.find(Some.class, id)).andReturn(mock);
```

, but how do I do the same for the 'remove' case?

I can't do (for example):

```
EasyMock.expect(this.mockManager.remove(rek)).andReturn(Boolean(true));
```

And if I do nothing, I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Unexpected method call EntityManager.remove(EasyMock for class my.package.Some)...
```

I need to test the logic before getting to remove part, but I don't care if it actually succeeds (would be a different thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `EasyMock.expect()`. Just use

```
this.mockManager.remove(rek);
```

while in the recording phase (before calling `replay()`).

If you want the mocked method, for example, to throw an exception or to be called twice, use `expectLastCal()`:

```
this.mockManager.remove(rek);
expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException());
//or expectLastCall().times(2);
```

Comment: I actually figured this just out by my self before I checked here again (though not the Exception part yet). You were fast. +1 For that.